# Python e o módulo ipaddress

Tags: python, ip, decimal

Olá,

Eu tenho um arquivo TXT contendo 340 mil linhas de endereços IP em decimal, exemplo: 16777262. Utilizando o módulo ipaddress eu consigo converter o decimal para o formato pontuado '1.0.0.46'. Conforme evidência abaixo:

```
>>> ipaddress.ip_address(16777262).__str__()
'1.0.0.46'
```

Quando eu crio o código para o Python ler cada linha e converter o decimal para IP, estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

**Código:**

```
import ipaddress

source_file = open('dcim_to_ip.txt')

for decimal_line in source_file:
    decimal = decimal_line.rstrip('\n')
    ipaddress.ip_address(decimal).__str__()
```

**Erro:**

```
ValueError: '16777262' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

Sinto que estou fazendo algo errado na forma que a informação é lida do arquivo TXT e passada para o módulo ipaddress. Como posso avançar aqui?

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia, Renan!

Não tenho experiência com esse package, mas o documento ["An introduction to the ipaddress module"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html#creating-address-network-interface-objects) indica que a função `ip_address` cria um instância de `IPv4Address` ou de `IPv6Address`, a partir de um inteiro ou de uma **string formatada como um ip valido**.

Isso significa que:

O código abaixo funciona, pois o parâmetro é um valor inteiro (assim como no seu primeiro exemplo)

```
>>> ipaddress.ip_address(19216801)
IPv4Address('1.37.57.161')
```

Este código também funciona, pois apesar de o parâmetro ser uma string, ele está formatado como um endereço de ip

```
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')
IPv4Address('192.168.0.1')
```

Já este exemplo é equivalente ao que você está tentando fazer, que é passar uma string não formatada como ip

```
>>> ipaddress.ip_address('19216801')
ValueError: '19216801' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

Quando você está iterando as linhas do seu arquivo, cada valor é uma string. Basta converter para um inteiro antes. Não precisa nem remover explicitamente o `\n` se quiser.

---

**Solução**

```
for decimal_line in source_file:
    ipaddress.ip_address(int(decimal_line)).__str__()
```